# iMessage delivery status different on iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

I sent today an iMessage through my iPhone, and on the iPhone there is still no "delivered" status, but when I checked on my iPad which is on the same AppleID there is status "delivered" indicated beneath the same iMessage... What is actually the right status??? How is this different status in the same iMessage possible???? Thnx Alen

Comment: I feel like apple is doing some tests to the iMessage server or something alike because I have the same inconsistency between iPhone and OSX Messages.app; I think if it says delivered in one device, its definitely delivered. My reasoning is that, sometimes I don't get the delivered on my Macbook but I get the delivered on my iPhone but through the reply I see that they have read it (as of they replied to my last message)

Answer (score 1):

I find that if you send an iMessage from iPhone/MacbookPro/iPad, it won't be status 'delivered ' on the sent device until the receiver got the message,but the status on the other devices with the same AppleID will show the status 'delivered' as soon as you sent the iMessage.

Comment: When the iMessage expires, I.e. if the recipient does not receive it after some days?

Comment: From personal experience its safe for about 9 hours (haven't checked farther than that)...

Answer (score 0):

You should check in Settings -> Messages the following:

- the adress you use to send & receive
- read receipt is on

If these are OK, you should turn off iMessages and turn it back on and then it should be OK!

Hope it helps!